# Having an variable reach 9223372036854775808 crashes my program

Tags: swift

Having a variable reach 9223372036854775808 crashes my program.

I have not been able to find any information.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var disview: UILabel!
    var dislikes = 1

    @IBAction func dislike(_ sender: Any) { //Add to dislikes VAR and refresh display
        dislikes += dislikes //when this reaches 9223372036854775808 my program crashes
        print(dislikes)
        disview.text = "\(dislikes)"
    }

    @IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) { //Reset dislikes varibles to 0 and refresh display
        dislikes = 0 
        print("reset dislikes")
        disview.text = "\(dislikes)"
    }
```

I get:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: That number won't fit in a signed 64-bit integer. Since you will never has so many dislikes, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @rmaddy He adds the number to itself, doubling it every time. Isn't that like 100 presses?

Comment: `print(Int.max)` and you would know why.

Comment: Doing print(Int.max) crashes my program, but I get the point

Comment: Off topic but why is dislikes starting on 1 rather than 0? Isn’t that a bit negative;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, integer overflow will crash your program in Swift.

If you want to allow overflow you can use the [overflow operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID37) &+ &- &*

```
dislikes = dislikes &+ dislikes
```

Comment: Or just `dislikes &+= dislikes`. Of course it should probably be `dislikes &+= 1`.